# Finding values based off Row and Columns input in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup, correlation

I have a very big correlation matrix that is very hard to navigate.
I want to make two dropdown menus to select two items (X and Y) and need a formula in google sheets to output the corresponding correlation.
I am aware of the method of doing this by putting the row and column number, as described [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/get-cell-value-by-address-row-column/) but I want to put in the values in the row and column, not their number.

I would appreciate the help.

thank you

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use INDEX() with two MATCH() formulas.

- The first MATCH() gets the row number for the label you selected
- The second MATCH() gets the column number for the second label

For example, if I have my drop-downs in B1 and B2 and the data in a Data! sheet:

```
=INDEX(Data!A1:ZZ, MATCH(B2,Data!A:A,false), MATCH(B1,Data!1:1,false))
```